# Chaining SSH commands via PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I am running a SSH2 command via PHP and am trying to chain the commands to answer the password prompts from the bash script I run.

```
wget url-to-bash-script
bash name-of-file.sh
```

After this it will prompt for

```
MySQL Password:
```

And:

```
Retype password:
```

It will then proceed to install the packages for LAMP

I have tried something like this with no luck;

$ssh->exec( "wget URL;bash installLAMP.sh; password; password");

Thanks!

Comment: How about `"wget URL; printf 'password\npassword\n' | bash installLAMP.sh"`

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to use is **expect**

Here are some examples on how to use it:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/